# normal Python function, C extension function, ctypes C function, what are the differences?

Tags: ctypes, bytecode, cpython

From my understanding and question:

- normal Python function is compiled into byte code, and be executed in a forever loop
- C extension function is written in C by user and integrated into interpreter, when executed, they are NOT being compiled into byte code? then how are they be called by interpreter any way?
- ctypes C function, they are loaded by ctypes(which itself is a Python C extension module?), ctypes use libffi to do data marshalling and interact with these C functions

what puzzles me is generally how Python interpreter call C functions in the first place?